# Fonts change when adding non-latin characters

Tags: css, linux, pdf, fonts, nightmare

I am using NightmareJS to print a PDF on Linux + Docker, one in English only and one Chinese-English mixed. I copied all fonts from my Mac to Docker for trial to avoid missing fonts.

That's what I get for the whole document:

Nightmare:

> - English only: Helvetica
> - English-Chinese: Arial-BoldMT + ArialUnicodeMS

Chrome on Mac:

> - English only: Helvetica
> - English-Chinese: Helvetica + PingFang TC

[See this detailed explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQyLT.png)

**Question**:

How can I avoid that Nightmare switches Helvetica to Arial? Chrome on Mac is the expected result.

Comment: I delete all commments

Comment: okay, i need to see the comments

Comment: you may not! they belong to me!

Comment: ok, then i wait for your other comments

Comment: you must wait a looooong time

Comment: nono...then may we go to Chat room?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187558/discussion-between-jeppe-and-daikeung).